# How to get dynamic cumulative data by condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I want to fetch cumulative data according to conditions

Example data set (update):

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow (
DT date,
Part_number varchAr(10),
sales_volume int
)
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-01','HDD','190000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-03','HDD','20000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-03','HDD','70000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-03','SDD','100000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-03','SDD','20000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-05','HDD','90000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-05','SDD','50000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-05','SDD','50000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-06','SDD','20000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-07','HDD','50000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-07','HDD','40000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-07','SDD','100000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-07','SDD','40000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-08','HDD','20000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-08','HDD','30000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-08','SDD','60000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-04-08','SDD','80000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-04-09','HDD','10000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-05-11','HDD','20000');
select * from stackoverflow;
```

If the running total is higher than the condition, it is reset and started with the following conditions.

Conditions

1. If the system is less than or equal to 200,000,
    
   "OK" is displayed in the remarks column whenever the value is more than  100000.
2. If the system is less than or equal to 30,000, 
   "OK" is displayed in the remarks column whenever the value is more than  80000.
3. If the bonded system is less than or equal to 400,000,
    
   "OK" is displayed in the remarks column whenever the value is more than  60,000.
4. If the system is less than or equal to 500,000,
    
   "OK" is displayed in the remarks column whenever the value is more than 40000.
5. If the system is larger than 500,000,
    
   "OK" is displayed in the remarks column every time over 30000.

```
    cum.sum <= 200000 || "OK" is displayed on DESC when it exceeds 100,000  
    cum.sum <= 300000 || "OK" is displayed on DESC when it exceeds 80,000
    cum.sum <= 400000 || "OK" is displayed on DESC when it exceeds 60,000
    cum.sum <= 500000 || "OK" is displayed on DESC when it exceeds 40,000
    cum.sum  > 500000 || "OK" is displayed on DESC when it exceeds 30,000
```

condition result 
- The Desc. column is nothing but a reminder of the results of the condition.

```
   DT     PARTS  COUNT      CUM.SUM    DESC.    
2018-03-01  HDD 190,000     190,000     OK
2018-03-03  HDD  20,000     210,000     
2018-03-03  HDD  70,000     280,000     
2018-03-03  SDD 100,000     100,000     OK
2018-03-03  SDD  20,000     120,000     
2018-03-05  HDD  90,000     370,000     OK
2018-03-05  SDD  50,000     170,000     
2018-03-05  SDD  50,000     220,000     OK
2018-03-06  SDD  20,000     240,000     
2018-03-07  HDD  50,000     420,000     
2018-03-07  HDD  40,000     460,000     OK
2018-03-07  SDD 100,000     340,000     OK
2018-03-07  SDD  40,000     380,000     
2018-03-08  HDD  20,000     480,000     
2018-03-08  HDD  30,000     510,000     OK
2018-03-08  SDD  60,000     440,000     OK
2018-04-08  SDD  80,000     520,000     OK
2018-04-09  HDD  10,000     520,000     
2018-05-11  HDD  20,000     540,000     OK
```

Desired result

```
    DT    PARTS  COUNT     CUM.SUM       
2018-03-01  HDD 190,000     190,000        
2018-03-03  SDD 100,000     100,000      
2018-03-05  HDD  90,000     370,000      
2018-03-05  SDD  50,000     220,000     
2018-03-07  HDD  40,000     460,000     
2018-03-07  SDD 100,000     340,000      
2018-03-08  HDD  30,000     510,000     
2018-03-08  SDD  60,000     440,000     
2018-04-08  SDD  80,000     520,000      
2018-05-11  HDD  20,000     540,000
```

=====================================================

Updated sample data sets and desired results.

I will explain it to everyone who has the question "OK."

Based on the HDD of the PARTS column,

[image: Example : HDD of the PARTS column]

1. The initial value is 190000 and exceeds 100,000, so "ok"
2. The condition is based on cum.sum data for the last date written "ok".

Comment: I don't understand whence the count is, and also the cumulative sums in your expected output do not seem to match to the sample data.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen  
I uploaded an image of intermediate processing. please check.

Comment: Please just show the starting sample data and the output you expect.

Comment: I don't understand your description of how the running total CUM.SUM is calculated. Looking at the intermediate processing image you posted, It appears you reset the total after line 3, but it is unclear what condition caused the reset and what the total was reset to. Can you please clarify? Also, your remark conditions do not fully match your processing sample. Instead of '... when it exceeds XXX' it seems it should be 'when >= XXX'. This matches your lines where the running total >= 500,000. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm really sorry. The data could not be validated correctly. I have updated the example data set and Desired result.Please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `Desc` column which I didn't understand the logic(obviously you'll use some basic `case..when` expressions), the following query helps you :

```
select dt as "DT", Part_number as "PARTS", sales_volume as "COUNT",
       sum(sales_volume) over (partition by Part_number order by dt) as "CUM.SUM",
       case when sales_volume >= 100000 then 'OK' end as "DESC."
  from stackoverflow
 order by dt, parts
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cc6036f40aef828639b111efda4e21e5)</kbd>

Comment: I'm really sorry. The data could not be validated correctly. I have updated the example data set and Desired result. Please confirm.

Comment: @Kyo Data related to "DESC." column is still unclear.

Comment: The Desc. column is nothing but a reminder of the results of the condition.

Comment: I posted the final output in the article below. confirm Please.

Answer (score 0):

This may help but except Desc part:

```
;WITH RuningTotal
AS(
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS SL
       ,*
from stackoverflow
)
SELECT * ,SUM (sales_volume) OVER (PARTITION BY Part_number ORDER BY SL,DT,Part_number) AS RunningTotal
FROM RuningTotal
ORDER BY DT,Part_number
```

Comparison with output and expected result.

[image]

Comment: I'm really sorry. The data could not be validated correctly. I have updated the example data set and Desired result.Please confirm.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I can't check today because I'm off work.  When I get to work tomorrow, I'll check and follow up.

Comment: I posted the final output in the article below. confirm Please.